# Client/ server java websocket using tyrus

Tags: java, websocket, glassfish, tyrus

I have been pouring over all of the questions asked here about using websockets in java, but none seem to shed any light on my problem. I have a server deployed to glassfish 4.0 with the context root removed, or basically set to "". This was done by the project lead for other reasons not pertaining to my code. I have published the server to a local glassfish installation and have verified this works with a simple 'ping' method. Here is my server endpoint code.

```
@ServerEndpoint("/test1")
public class UploadWebSocketEndpoint implements Serializable{

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 9054820114345305531L;

public UploadWebSocketEndpoint() { super(); }

@OnOpen
public void open(Session session)
{
    if(session != null)
    {
        System.out.println(session.getId() + " has opened a connection");
        try
        {
//              session.getBasicRemote().sendText("Connection Established");
        }catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

@OnClose
public void close(Session session)
{
    if(session != null)
    {
        System.out.println(session.getId() + " has closed the session");
        try
        {
//              session.close(new CloseReason(CloseReason.CloseCodes.NORMAL_CLOSURE, "ended process"));
        }catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

@OnMessage
public String requestAccess(String message, Session session)
{
    System.out.println("recieved message: " + message + " from user " + session.getId());
    return "";
}

@OnError
public void onError(Throwable t)
{
    new Exception(t).getStackTrace();
}
```

}

After looking at as many examples and all the documentation I could find, this appears to be correct. Now here is my client code using the tyrus client standalone jar.

```
@ClientEndpoint
public class ClientEndpointSocket
{
Session userSession = null;
private MessageHandler messageHandler;

public ClientEndpointSocket(URI endpointURI)
{
    try
    {
        WebSocketContainer container = ContainerProvider.getWebSocketContainer();
        System.out.println("conatiner: " + ContainerProvider.getWebSocketContainer().getClass());
        System.out.println("attempting to connect to server at endpoint: " + endpointURI.toString());
        container.connectToServer(this, endpointURI);
    }catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@OnOpen
public void onOpen(Session session)
{
    try
    {
        System.out.println("opening web socket");
        this.userSession = session;
    }catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


@OnMessage
public String onMessage(String message, Session session)
{
    if(this.messageHandler != null)
    {
        this.messageHandler.handleMessage(message);
    }
    return null;
}


@OnClose
public void onClose(Session session, CloseReason closeReason)
{
    System.out.println("closing websocket");
    this.userSession = null;
}

public void sendMessage(String message)
{
    this.userSession.getAsyncRemote().sendText(message);
}

public void addMessageHandler(MessageHandler msgHandler)
{
    this.messageHandler = msgHandler;
}

public static interface MessageHandler 
{
    public void handleMessage(String message);
}
}
```

And here is my main class for the client

```
public class EncryptionMain  {


public static void main(String[] args)
{
    try
    {   

        WebSocketContainer container = ContainerProvider.getWebSocketContainer();
        String uri = "ws://localhost:8080/test1";
        System.out.println("connecting to server: " + uri);
        container.connectToServer(ClientEndpointSocket.class, URI.create(uri)); 

    }catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
}
```

And finally, the stacktrace:

```
javax.websocket.DeploymentException: Handshake error.
at org.glassfish.tyrus.client.ClientManager$3$1.run(ClientManager.java:674)
at org.glassfish.tyrus.client.ClientManager$3.run(ClientManager.java:712)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at org.glassfish.tyrus.client.ClientManager$SameThreadExecutorService.execute(ClientManager.java:866)
at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:112)
at org.glassfish.tyrus.client.ClientManager.connectToServer(ClientManager.java:511)
at org.glassfish.tyrus.client.ClientManager.connectToServer(ClientManager.java:317)
at main.java.application.EncryptionMain.main(EncryptionMain.java:34)
Caused by: org.glassfish.tyrus.core.HandshakeException: Response code was not 101: 404.
at org.glassfish.tyrus.client.TyrusClientEngine.processResponse(TyrusClientEngine.java:320)
at org.glassfish.tyrus.container.grizzly.client.GrizzlyClientFilter.handleHandshake(GrizzlyClientFilter.java:346)
at org.glassfish.tyrus.container.grizzly.client.GrizzlyClientFilter.handleRead(GrizzlyClientFilter.java:315)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

If you need any more information on the project please let me know. With the 404 error I assumed my url was incorrect, although I have tested the server and it does reside at localhost/app for http resources, which from my understanding would mean the ws: would sit at localhost:8080/"here". If any information in here is incorrect or lacking, once again, please let me know. Thanks for any help in advance

Comment: Just realized I had left the main class changed from the way I had used it initially. To begin with, I had called my overloaded constructor of the client endpoint and created the server from inside THAT class, not the main. the main class code looked like so:                          `WebSocketServerManager webSock = new WebSocketServerManager(new URI("ws://localhost:8080/test1"));
   
   //add listener
   webSock.addMessageHandler(new WebSocketServerManager.MessageHandler() {
    public void handleMessage(String message)
    {
     System.out.println("message here: " + message);
    }
   });`